# Randomize external port when doing NAT with iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

I want to configure a NAT behavior different from the default one implemented by `iptables`.

In this example:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 193.49.142.107:2000-400
```

The default behavior of NAT implemented by `iptables` is Endpoint independent.
This means, all sessions initiated from the same host will have the same 'external' (IP, Port Number) even if there's a range of ports.

I need to know what are the flags or options to be modified in order to have a different port number for each session.

Comment: You want each outbound connection to have a different port number, correct?  What makes you think your system isn't doing that already?

Comment: I've already tested the rule by sinnifing packets and for 2 different sessions it's always the same port number that is affected.

Comment: What does `sudo iptables -vnL -t nat` show?

Comment: @HaTiMuX: How do you check "2 different sessions it's always the same port number"?

Comment: @Creek for the specific rule it shows ... to:175.45.14.88:90-100 which means there is a port ranger. I think --random does the work.

Comment: @Gnouc I'm using a python script in the receiving machine which is listening to the PREROUTING chain. When packets arrive I redirect them to my script using an iptable rule with the nfqueue option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*SNAT* accepts a `--random` option (from [iptables-extensions](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html#TARGET_EXTENSIONS) manpage):

```
--random
       If  option --random is used then port mapping will be randomized
       (kernel >= 2.6.21).
```

So I'd try something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 193.49.142.107:2000-4000 --random
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it and it's working for this specific case.